# Why does DateTime need to be a byte[] in Entity Framework? And How to I set it ?

Tags: entity-framework, datetime, dbcontext

I have a DBContext with a DateTime (in the db) that has been defined as a byte[] in the EF. So How do I send a byte[] that representing the current date??

Comment: Why do you defined it as byte[]? That makes no sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time should not come across as a byte array datatype.  If you're using SQL Server, it's possible you declared your datatype as timestamp instead of datetime, as it shows up as a byte array in code.  The timestamp type has been renamed to rowversion in more recent versions of SQL Server to be a bit more clear, as it doesn't hold any type of time data.

Comment: You are a genius! You are right.. I set it as a time stamp.. so no wonder I could not find an answer to this question!